# Media Queries: Icons on Navigation bar

Tags: html

I am currently creating a website that has media queries. I already have a normal navigation however when the webpage size reduces to a mobile size, I would like for the navigation to switch to another navigation bar which I have created, which includes icons which makes it easier for mobile users

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 50px) {
  <div class = "navbar">
  <a href="Home.html"><img src="Images/houseicon.png"/></a>
  <a href="Education.html"><img src="Images/educationicon.png"/></a>
  <a href="Contact%20Information.html"><img s**strong text**rc="Images/contactmeicon.png"/></a>
    </div>}
```

Comment: Did you add a media query for the other navigation bar class(es)? Something like `min-width: 970px`? You should also add  a max-width property to your media query above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add html to media query...
Html is part of html page
You just need to set below css with media query in your css file or in your  tag.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) { .navbar a img{ width:50px !important; height:50px !important;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to show navigation properly on responsiveness mobile view.

Code::

`@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

.nav img { 
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }

} `

Note:: height: 100px; and width: 100px; 
100px, is just for reference, please update height and width with your actual image size.